# Two dimensional array bring returned when expecting one demension

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to getting a list of sub categories out of a MYSQL table. I seem to be getting a two dimension array 
I'm using this is to get the data:

```
SELECT category_id
FROM category
WHERE parent_id =".$category_id." && is_visible=1;
```

And this to fill the array:

```
$r=0;
$child_row_ids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($child_rows))
{
  $r++;
  $child_row_ids[$r]=$row;
}
```

This is what I get when I do a var_dump

```
array(3) { [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "5741" ["category_id"]=> string(4) "5741" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "5773" ["category_id"]=> string(4) "5773" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "5774" ["category_id"]=> string(4) "5774" } }
```

I don't understand why I'm getting a two dimensional array.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: That's because `$row` is an array, and you're appending a new array `$row` to `$child_row_ids` in each iteration of `while` loop. What's your expected output?

Comment: replace `$child_row_ids[$r]=$row;` with `$child_row_ids[]=$row['category_id'];`

Comment: That's just what I wanted Rajdeep Paul. Post that is an answer and I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question Alex.

Comment: @RichardYoung It seems I don't have to, Barmar just posted one. :-)

Comment: You gave me the answer before he did so I'll accept yours. It helps your reputation.

Comment: @RichardYoung You can *accept* Barmar's answer, no issues. Glad I could help. :-) I've already given +1 to his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array (it says so right in its name). Since you're setting each element of the new array to an array, you get a 2-dimensional array.

If you just want an array of IDs, you have to index the array that it returns.

```
$child_row_ids[$r]=$row['category_id'];
```